# Reject a change in FullCalendar?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, fullcalendar

Is there a way in FullCalendar to reject a change? For example, when I move an event and then call a server function to update the db, if that returns false (db update failed) can I reject the change so that the view stays synced to the database?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using drag & drop for moving events, take a look at the `eventDrop` callback, which has a `revertFunc` option that you can use to revert the state if your Ajax call fails. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

Comment: Thanks, if you answer the question I will accept!

Comment: YW! Added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using drag & drop for moving events, take a look at the `eventDrop` callback, which has a `revertFunc` option that you can use to revert the state if your Ajax call fails.

[arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop)